# Idiomatic way in Jekyll to inherit default data if project specific data unavailable

Tags: jekyll

I am completely new to Jekyll.  I did something like this:

```
  {% assign top_nav = site.data.menus %}
  {% if site.data.orgs[site.orgData].menus %}
    {% assign top_nav = site.data.orgs[site.orgData].menus %}
  {% endif %}
  <ul>
    {% for menu in top_nav %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ menu.url }}">{{ menu.title }}</a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

Basically, I will grab an array of navigation items from a default folder.  But if I notice the existence of a menu for a specific organization, then I will override the menu provided by the default folder.

What I don't like about this approach is I now have hundreds of places in my jekyll templates that does this if statement check.  If this were any other scripting programming language, I would define a function like `function($org_name,$prop) {return $site.data.orgs[$org_name][$prop] ? $site.data.orgs[$org_name][$prop] : $site.data[$prop]; }` .  What would be the idiomatic way to achieve the same objective in jekyll?

---

I tried a variation of David Jacquel's suggestion by doing this

**./org_var.html**

```
{% assign prop = include.prop %}

{% assign orgVar = site.data[prop] %}
{% if site.data.orgs[site.orgData][prop] %}
  {% assign orgVar = site.data.orgs[site.orgData][prop] %}
{% endif %}
```

**./_include/nav.html**

```
{% include_relative ../org_var.html prop=menus %}
{% for menu in orgVar %}
... print menu items
```

**./_layout/header.html**

```
{% include_relative ../org_var prop='electronics.televisions' %}
{% for tv in orgVar%}
{{ tv.modelName }}
... print tv values
{% endfor %}
```

But I get a syntax error in `../org_var.html`  saying `{% include_relative file.ext param='value' param2='value' %}`  .  The documentation says I can't use relative path with `include` or `include_relative`.  How do I make my `org_var.html` a reusable and global function?  And will `electronics.televisions` even evaluate properly to the proper path of my `site.data.org.[site.orgData][...path]` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just realized there is a `default:` modifier for a variable like [smarty templates](https://www.smarty.net/).

```
{% assign top_nav = site.data.orgs[site.orgData].menus | default: site.data.menus %}
```

Comment: Is it ok for you ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jekyll includes](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/).

From anywhere you want to use your include :

```
{% include nav.html org_name=org_name prop=prop %}
```

Will call **_include/nav.html** that can be something like this :

```
{% assign org_name = include.org_name %}
{% assign prop = include.prop %}

{% if site.data.orgs[org_name][prop] %}
  {% assign top_nav = site.data.orgs[site.orgData].menus %}
{% else %}
  {% assign top_nav = site.data.orgs[site.orgData].menus %}
{% endif %}
<ul>
  {% for menu in top_nav %}
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks !  I tried a variation of what you suggested above but I get syntax errors.  Can you tell me how I can update my approach to work?